# Lightbox Gallery in Bootstrap 3 template?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, lightbox

I'm making a one-page website for a friend of mine. She's a fashion designer, and she would love to have a one-page website based on the "Stylish Portfolio" Bootstrap template --> http://startbootstrap.com/stylish-portfolio

However, I want to put in a lightbox gallery in the section below where it says "Some of our work".

I was thinking of getting the BlueImp Lightbox gallery or the Bootstrap Lightbox: http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/#usage

Both match what I was looking for.

However, I have tried to insert it into the HTML-code, but without any luck!
Does anybody have any experience in inserting/adding lightbox galleries to a Bootstrap template? And if so, how should I approach this task?

Comment: did you download lightbox library?

Comment: The blueimp gallery is great. Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreciate the help here!
I'm at work right now, but will provide the necessary information as soon as I can get back home and continue working on my little project :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I used BlueImp instead to insert a lightbox gallery :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments from your question, they wanted to see your code so they know where and how they can help you. It would also let us know how much code we would need to supply without actually spoon-feeding you the answers so that you can get your answers as well as still learn :)

With that, I'm gonna assume that you're a beginner and thus supply most of the codes that you need as well as explanations on what I'm doing. I'm gonna take bootstrap-lightbox as an example.

First off, you need to download the files from the site. After downloading the files, you would be able to see that this contains 4 files, namely bootstrap-lightbox.css, bootstrap-lightbox.js and their min files. (min files are just compressed versions of the files in order to lessen its size)

Now, it's basically just needing to plug-in those files into your project.

Assuming that you put the files into their respective js and css folders in your project, this is how they would look like:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"> //plug this inside your <head> tags

<script src="js/bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
```

After plugging those in your files, then its a matter of just using the html code that you found in the site :)

```
<div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class='lightbox-content'>
        <img src="image.png">
        <div class="lightbox-caption"><p>Your caption here</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreciate the help here!
I'm at work right now, but will provide the necessary information as soon as I can get back home and continue working on my little project :-)